# Planets in solar system are not moving (functions are written)

Tags: python, vpython

In my OOP version of the Solar system my planets are displayed but not moving. The functions are written but somehow it doesn't work. I think it might be something little but I didn't found it out. I already tried to write planets lower case everywhere, but that didn't help. In my normal version it worked but now only the planets are generated and nothing else is happening. They're just stuck to their initial position.

```
from vpython import *

#constants

#array 
planets = []

class Sphere(object):
    def __init__(self, pos, radius, make_trail):
        self.pos = pos
        self.radius = radius
        self.make_trail = make_trail


class planet(Sphere):
    def __init__(self, pos, radius, make_trail, mass, velocity):
        super().__init__(pos, radius, make_trail)
        self.mass = mass
        self.velocity = velocity
        planetSphere = sphere(pos = self.pos,
                              radius = self.radius,
                              make_trail = self.make_trail,
                              mass = self.mass,
                              velocity = self.velocity)


sun = planet(pos=vec(0,0,0), radius=s_rad1*1.5,
             make_trail=True, mass=2e30,
             velocity=vec(0,0,0))
mercury = planet(pos=vec(ae/3,0,0), radius=s_rad1/1.5,
                 make_trail=True, mass=3.25e23,
                 velocity=vec(0,0,-47000))
#...Other Planets
pluto = planet(pos=vec(ae*39.37,0,0), radius=s_rad1/2.4,
               make_trail=True, mass=1.3e22,
               velocity=vec(0,0,-4740))

planets.extend((mercury, venus, earth, mars, jupiter, saturn, uranus, neptun, pluto))

dt = 10000
time = 0.1

while (True):

    rate(framerate) 
    g_forceS = vec(0,0,0)

    for planet in planets:
        g_force = g * sun.mass * planet.mass * (sun.pos - planet.pos).norm()  / (sun.pos - planet.pos).mag2
        g_forceS -= g_force

        planet.velocity = planet.velocity + ( g_force / planet.mass) * dt 
        planet.pos += planet.velocity * dt 

    sun.velocity = sun.velocity + ( g_forceS / sun.mass) * dt 
    sun.pos += sun.velocity * dt
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Not possible to debug without the whole program, including the constants.